# How does the Category Ids of a product are stored and retrieved?

Tags: magento2

I've been trying to understand, How Magento is managing the category_ids attribute for product in database and on code level? I noticed this attribute is handled in a different way to the other **static** backend_type  eav attributes.

If someone has already got chance to analyze it, his finding can save time for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a static attribute, this a relation between two entities and it's stored in the `catalog_category_product` table. The model related is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLink`

Take a look at `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product`, you can see the `getCategoryIds` method that calls `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CategoryLink::getCategoryLinks`